# Error when load data from csv with liquibase into enum column

Tags: java, postgresql, csv, enums, liquibase

I came across an error and can't find a way to solve it. Error occurs when I'm trying to load data from csv into the table with enum column using Liquibase.

In first, I create the enum type and table like this:

```
<changeSet author="enbirr" id="create-table">
<sql>CREATE TYPE product_type AS ENUM (
        'deposits',
        'credits'
    );
</sql>

<createTable tableName="test_table">
    <column name="guid" type="uuid">
        <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="test_table_pk"/>
    </column>
    <column name="product" type="product_type">
        <constraints nullable="false"/>
    </column>
</createTable> 
</changeSet>
```

Then, I insert data from data.csv:

```
 "guid"|"product"
 "5672b9c1-8fd3-4dc8-a67f-4498d9747c66"|"deposits"
 "3458f613-ab6b-462b-8983-52dfac238f56"|"credits"
```

using next changeset:

```
<changeSet author="enbirr" id="fill-data">
        <loadData
                file="csv/data.csv"
                relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                separator="|"
                tableName="test_table"/>
</changeSet>
```

And when I start my Java app that runs these Liquibase changesets, I receive the next error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "product" is of type product_type but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 123
```

Anybody knows how to teach Liquibase to cast string to custom enum type?

PS version of liquibase-core - 4.5.0

Comment: I don't use `liquibase` but I did find: [loadData](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/load-data.html) `Nested properties` with `column` and `type`. And then [LOAD_DATA Types](https://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/change/core/LoadDataChange.LOAD_DATA_TYPE.html?_ga=2.156928507.1389891823.1643646803-1974242232.1643646803). You might try `UNKNOWN`.

Comment: I should have added I tested doing `\copy` from a CSV to a table with an `enum` and there where no issues. The error seems to come from `liquibase` comparing the type it inferred from the data to the type declared on the table.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, thanks for suggestion. I tried set UNKNOWN type for column with enum type in changeset:
```<changeSet author="enbirr" id="fill-data">
        <loadData
                file="csv/data.csv"
                relativeToChangelogFile="true"
                separator="|"
                tableName="test_table">
            <column name="guid" type="uuid"/>
            <column name="product" type="UNKNOWN"/>
       </loadData>
</changeSet>```

But it didn't help.

Comment: Yesterday discussed this case with our project architect. He said that there are two ways to solve this problem: rework some Liquibase internal classes or just don't use enums. Obviously, first way is more complex. Moreover, using of enums can bring us other problems in future. For current project there is no any important reason to use enums, so I just leave this problem unsolved :) 
Thanks for help, @AdrianKlaver!

Answer (score 0):

I am using type `other` and then solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).